# Using different languages with MVC Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a url format like `www.site.com/controller/action` that looks like `www.site.com/account/login`

If I want to display this depending on the current culture/language I want to have different url based on the current language, for example

```
www.site.com/account/login -> www.site.com/en/newaccount/login
                              www.site.com/fr/compte/alogin
                              www.site.com/de/konto/ulogin
```

How can I do this in MVC RegisterRoutes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this will work but i would have tried this one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{language}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", language = "en", action = "Index", area = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I already tried this but language parameter is mandatory in your example

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dresel's [RouteLocalization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RouteLocalization.Mvc/)